# What are the grandmas plotting?

Tags: cookie-clicker

In Cookie Clicker, there is an upgrade called "One Mind".  Besides giving the usual bonus to something (in this case grandmas), it comes with a red warning: "Note: The grandmothers are growing restless. Do not encourage them."

If you try to purchase it the page pops up a warning:

> Warning : purchasing this will have unexpected, and potentially undesirable results!
>   It's all downhill from here. You have been warned!
>   Purchase anyway?

With the options to purchase anyway or cancel.  So far, I've always canceled.

What happens if I buy "One Mind"?

Comment: @BillyMailman Ah, you're right.  Searching for "[cookie clicker one mind](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=cookie+clicker+one+mind)" did not and does not bring up the question you link, so I didn't see it :)

Comment: Yeah, because tag names are often not used in questions/titles/etc., it's best to search for them as an actual tag, as in http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcookie-clicker%5D+one+mind